# Java - How to shorten a lengthy String.format so that it is <120 chars

Tags: java, string

I tried searching for similar threads, but I am not finding much.

I am trying to shorten the following statement so that it is under 120 characters (currently 145):

`return (String.format("I am driving a %s and I love it. It has a top speed of %d miles per hour and it is worth %d", carMake, topSpeed, value));`

Thank you!

Comment: so it's not about the length of the string but the length of the line of code?!

Answer (score 2):

You can break the string literal in some lines:

```java
return String.format(
        "I am driving a %s and I love it. " + 
        "It has a top speed of %d miles per hour and " + 
        "it is worth %d", 
        carMake, topSpeed, value);
```

The format can be changed as desired, but note the empty space on the end of each line (but the last).

The concatenation of string literals is *done* by the compiler, so there is no performance loss involved when splitting string literals in that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this if you want multiline output.  It became an official construct in Java 15.

```
String carMake = "Ferrari";
int topSpeed = 100;
int value = 250000;

String s = 
        """
        I am driving a %s and I love it.
        It has a top speed of %d miles per hour and
        it is worth $%,d.
        """.formatted(carMake, topSpeed, value);

System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
I am driving a Ferrari and I love it.
It has a top speed of 100 miles per hour and
it is worth $250,000.
```

Comment: Isn’t this indented unless you trim it?

Comment: No, because they are they are all indented the same.  So the leading white space is incidental white space and is removed.  If the second line was indented an extra 2 spaces, they would print the same as before except the second one would be indented the extra spaces.  Check out [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/text_blocks/index.html#incidental-white-space) as a fairly detailed overview.

Comment: I have not worked with text blocks yet, and I apparently misunderstood what `stripIndent()` was for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Store the string in a variable

```
String strToFormat = "I am driving a %s and I love it. It has a top speed of %d miles per hour and it is worth %d";
return String.format(strToFormat, carMake, topSpeed, value);
```

Comment: Thank you! I am still learning how Java works, but hopefully I will get better in the future :)

Comment: @vicbur04 that is nothing related at all with Java. That is only a variable store, that exists in most languages ;)